# Theme Colors Glitch in Neovim

Tags: vim, neovim

With `termguicolors` enabled, some themes seem to color comments and other content the same as the background in Neovim. The current uncooperative themes:

- [sonokai](https://github.com/sainnhe/sonokai)
- [challenger-deep](https://github.com/challenger-deep-theme/vim)
- [gruvbox-material](https://github.com/sainnhe/gruvbox-material)

A screenshot with `challenger_deep`:
[image: screenshot]

As you can see, `<!doctype html>` on line 1 is invisible, as well as the content between the `h1` tags.

I have tried setting `$TERM` to different values, to no effect. Also, this happens in alacritty, xfce4-terminal, and termite (all the terminals I have installed). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my font was to blame. It does not have an italic variation, and the terminals simply output nothingness if a font has no italics but a program wants to output italics. I changed the font, and everything works fine now.